# When to make an Object parcelable rather than just sending the primitive variables?

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

After researching for a while there is still something unclear for me:

When is it worth to implement Parcelable rather than just getting the variables and send them to a new Activity?
If i search for example for something like "RecyclerView click open new Activity", almost everyone posts code that extracts the values with getter methods in Activity 1 and sends them via multiple .putExtra calls to Activity 2. Almost no one seems to suggest to implement Parcelable.
I also fail to see where Parcelable saves effort or makes the code more maintainable, since i have to call .getXXX for every value in the target Activity anyways.

So let's say I have a RecyclerView, I want to open a new Activity on Button click and i want to send 3 variables out of 1 Object from 1 ArrayList. Should i send the variables directly over 3 .putExtra calls or implement Parcelable and send the whole Object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case sending the 3 primitive values with putExtra should be enough.  Parcelable is to send objects.  Normally these objects contain objects which contain other objects or array of objects.  In summary it is used to send complex objects.  It's also necessary if you need to send an object to your service as part of the body of a request.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Parcelable if u have less no. Of data elements because serialization itself  take some time. But sending them individually will be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Using parcelable for something as trivial as this would be an overkill as it involves the overhead of constructing a new object for only a few values. It would be better if you just add the .putExtra() calls for the values you need to share, that should be enough, as the others before me said. :)

Comment: :) @Florian please mark the answer as correct if you think it best answers your question. :)